# How to return video (flv) path to display in flowplayer?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, video, flowplayer

I would like to integrate flowplayer in ASP mvc 3 application.
I'm using SQL Server 2008. Database contains path to files as well which are stored in folder. I wrote library which is able to convert video to flv. Now i would like to use this video in page.

Does anyone have knowledge how to implement that?

I found the flowplayer sample code.

http://flowplayer.org/docs/

But I'm looking for codebehind solution (C#) how to implement something like that (how to return path to video).
If anyone have some code I'll be grateful for help.

Please take a look.

```
    public string FindMusicByID(int musicID)
    {
        var pathh = from plik in _data.musicMusicTables
                    where plik.musicMusicID == musicID
                    select new PathToFile { PathFile = plik.musicMusicPath };
        return pathh.ToString();
    }
```

This is the linq part code which i'm using. FindMusicByID(int musicID) return path to .flv file. I'm looking for how to send output filepath to webpage. I would like to use this path in flowplayer.

`<div class="flowplayer" data-engine="flash"> <video src="some path"></video>`

Fox example this is my ouptut path d:\file.flv

I suppose that it's necessary to send output to JavaScript.
How can i insert path into flowplayer by ID?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking for, but if you want to know how to return `.flv` file for your player you just need `Action` that return `FileStremResult` using this mimetype: `video/x-flv`

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
public string FindMusicByID(int musicID)
    {
        var pathh= from plik in _data.musicMusicTables
                    where plik.musicMusicID == musicID
                    select new PathToFile { PathFile = plik.musicMusicPath };
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition {
                FileName = "filename",
                Inline = false
            };
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return File(path, asset.AssetType.MimeType); 
        }
```